# Sql like query with variable?

Tags: php, sql

I have this function:

```
function word($arg){

    echo ''.$arg.'';
    //echoes test

    require ('config.php');

    $requestSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db where eng LIKE '%$arg%' order by id ASC LIMIT 10", $connection);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($requestSQL))
    {
        echo ''.$row['id'].': '.$row['eng'].'<br>';
    }

}
```

Gets triggered by:

```
$number = $explode[1];
word($number);
```

---

But doesn't echo values from the database, nothing at all.
If I echo $arg (in the function), it shows the value. If I replace in my sql query: '%$arg%' with '%test%', it echoes the correct value.

Is the '%$arg%' syntax wrong?

Comment: Also if I replace: $number = $explode[1]; with $number = 'test', the sql query echoes values.

Comment: Echo your query. Does it look correct? Run it directly in your database. Do you get any results? As a note, you are wide open for SQL injection. `mysql_*` functions are removed in PHP7 and deprecated in previous versions. It is strongly recommended that you use PDO or mysqli, and take advantage of prepared statements.

Comment: What is in $explode array ?

Comment: Maybe you could show us what the array `$explode` has, then perhaps we'll have a better chance of helping you find your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a proper concat

```
"SELECT * FROM db where eng LIKE concat('%', '$arg', '%') order by id ASC LIMIT 10"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, all you do is: `LIKE %{$arg}%`. Because I am assuming that `$arg` is a text value. If a variable is a text value then you must do this to keep it working. You wrap text variables in `{}`.

Also, never . . . EVER use `mysql_*`, you should move to `mysqli_*` or PDO/OOP. It's just good practice.

### Update

---

You can't use variables within `mysql_query("", $connection)` quotes. Instead, do this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE eng LIKE '%{$arg}%' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10";

// then use this variable as a replacement for the quotes in the mysql_query().    

$set = mysql_query($query, $connection); // like so . . .

// mysql_fetch_assoc() is the same as mysql_fetch_array().

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($set)) {
  echo "".$row['id'].": ".$row['eng']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't echo any values: SELECT * FROM db where eng LIKE '%{$arg}%' order by id ASC LIMIT 10

Comment: `where` also should be `WHERE`.

Comment: And you should probably try this: `echo " ".$row['id'].": ".$row['eng']."<br>";`

Comment: `where` is not case sensitive. Upper case is just preferred for keywords for readability.

Comment: Yes I know that, but it's good practice to keep it capitalized.

Comment: Oh wait, I'm pretty sure I just figured it out. You aren't allowed to add variables _within_ a `mysql_query("no variables allowed here", $connection);`.

Comment: Still doesn't work with the code you provided. I get no echoed values. I think the problem is $explode[1]. If I use something else like $var = 'test' instead of $var = $explode[1], then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so stupid, actually $explode[1]; was returning the correct value but had a blank line in the source code. So I had to use trim and now it works.